# Adding an RSS feed to the Windows 8 start screen

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui, start-screen

Loving Windows 8, but it would be nice if I could put my own newsfeeds into the boxes on the start screen. At present you can just choose to have a "News" app, but surely there's a way to replace that with an RSS feed of your choice?

[image]

Is there an App, or some other way that I can do this?

Comment: I am sure once Oct 26 hits there will be dozens of Modern UI RSS applications.  You might be able to find one today, if you look, clearly we can't make suggestions.

Comment: Post an answer yourself if you find any good ones :)

Comment: If you're currently using Windows 10, please refer to my answer at: http://superuser.com/a/978664/323140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Dark RSS Reader](https://www.darkrss.ch/) Windows 8 Metro App from the Windows Store.

Unfortunately it's not directly displaying the recent new in the tile, but anyway useful.

[image]